# What's going on in my custom list view control that leads to rows either partially or fully not being redrawn when scrolling?

Tags: c, winapi, scroll, gdi

I'm building a custom listview control as the standard comctl32.dll one does not adequately fit my needs. Things seem to be going well for what I have so far, except for scrolling.

At first, things look like this (under wine, but real Windows is affected too);

[image: normal]

The form of corruption changes depending on the type of scrolling used. If I scroll using the mouse wheel, every few rows is corrupted:

[image: wheel corruption]

And if I scroll by dragging the thumb, this happens:

[image: thumb corruption]

In both cases, clicking somewhere will redraw everything, and the corruption goes away.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the code; I will explain how it works below:

```
// 19 october 2014
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501       /* according to Microsoft's winperf.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>

// #qo LIBS: user32 kernel32 gdi32 comctl32

// TODO
// - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/09/54826.aspx (relies on the integrality parts? IDK)
//  - might want to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/17/54944.aspx instead
// - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
// - hscroll (harder)
//  - keyboard navigation
//  - mousewheel navigation

#define tableWindowClass L"gouitable"

struct table {
    HWND hwnd;
    HFONT defaultFont;
    HFONT font;
    intptr_t selected;
    intptr_t count;
    intptr_t firstVisible;
    intptr_t pagesize;      // in rows
    int wheelCarry;
    HWND header;
    int headerHeight;
    intptr_t nColumns;
    HIMAGELIST imagelist;
    int imagelistHeight;
};

static LONG rowHeight(struct table *t)
{
    HFONT thisfont, prevfont;
    TEXTMETRICW tm;
    HDC dc;
    LONG ret;

    dc = GetDC(t->hwnd);
    if (dc == NULL)
        abort();
    thisfont = t->font;     // in case WM_SETFONT happens before we return
    prevfont = (HFONT) SelectObject(dc, thisfont);
    if (prevfont == NULL)
        abort();
    if (GetTextMetricsW(dc, &tm) == 0)
        abort();
    if (SelectObject(dc, prevfont) != (HGDIOBJ) (thisfont))
        abort();
    if (ReleaseDC(t->hwnd, dc) == 0)
        abort();
    ret = tm.tmHeight;
    if (ret < t->imagelistHeight)
        ret = t->imagelistHeight;
    return ret;
}

static void redrawAll(struct table *t)
{
    if (InvalidateRect(t->hwnd, NULL, TRUE) == 0)
        abort();
    if (UpdateWindow(t->hwnd) == 0)
        abort();
}

static RECT realClientRect(struct table *t)
{
    RECT r;

    if (GetClientRect(t->hwnd, &r) == 0)
        abort();
    r.top += t->headerHeight;
    return r;
}

static void recomputeHScroll(struct table *t)
{
    HDITEMW item;
    intptr_t i;
    int width = 0;
    RECT r;
    SCROLLINFO si;

    // TODO count dividers
    for (i = 0; i < t->nColumns; i++) {
        ZeroMemory(&item, sizeof (HDITEMW));
        item.mask = HDI_WIDTH;
        if (SendMessageW(t->header, HDM_GETITEM, (WPARAM) i, (LPARAM) (&item)) == FALSE)
            abort();
        width += item.cxy;
    }

    if (GetClientRect(t->hwnd, &r) == 0)
        abort();
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof (SCROLLINFO));
    si.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE;
    si.nPage = r.right - r.left;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = width - 1;            // - 1 because endpoints inclusive
    SetScrollInfo(t->hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
}

static void finishSelect(struct table *t)
{
    if (t->selected < 0)
        t->selected = 0;
    if (t->selected >= t->count)
        t->selected = t->count - 1;
    // TODO update only the old and new selected items
    redrawAll(t);
    // TODO scroll to the selected item if it's not entirely visible
}

static void keySelect(struct table *t, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO figure out correct behavior with nothing selected
    if (t->count == 0)      // don't try to do anything if there's nothing to do
        return;
    switch (wParam) {
    case VK_UP:
        t->selected--;
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        t->selected++;
        break;
    case VK_PRIOR:
        t->selected -= t->pagesize;
        break;
    case VK_NEXT:
        t->selected += t->pagesize;
        break;
    case VK_HOME:
        t->selected = 0;
        break;
    case VK_END:
        t->selected = t->count - 1;
        break;
    default:
        // don't touch anything
        return;
    }
    finishSelect(t);
}

static void selectItem(struct table *t, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int x, y;
    LONG h;

    x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    h = rowHeight(t);
    y += t->firstVisible * h;
    y -= t->headerHeight;
    y /= h;
    t->selected = y;
    if (t->selected >= t->count)
        t->selected = -1;
    finishSelect(t);
}

// TODO on initial show the items are not arranged properly
// TODO the lowest visible row does not redraw properly after scrolling
// TODO the row behind the header bar does not redraw properly after scrolling
static void vscrollto(struct table *t, intptr_t newpos)
{
    SCROLLINFO si;
    RECT scrollArea;

    if (newpos < 0)
        newpos = 0;
    if (newpos > (t->count - t->pagesize))
        newpos = (t->count - t->pagesize);

    scrollArea = realClientRect(t);

    // negative because ScrollWindowEx() is "backwards"
    if (ScrollWindowEx(t->hwnd, 0, (-(newpos - t->firstVisible)) * rowHeight(t),
        &scrollArea, &scrollArea, NULL, NULL,
        SW_ERASE | SW_INVALIDATE) == ERROR)
        abort();
    t->firstVisible = newpos;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof (SCROLLINFO));
    si.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_RANGE;
    si.nPage = t->pagesize;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = t->count - 1;     // nMax is inclusive
    si.nPos = t->firstVisible;
    SetScrollInfo(t->hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
}

static void vscrollby(struct table *t, intptr_t n)
{
    vscrollto(t, t->firstVisible + n);
}

static void wheelscroll(struct table *t, WPARAM wParam)
{
    int delta;
    int lines;
    UINT scrollAmount;

    delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
    if (SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES, 0, &scrollAmount, 0) == 0)
        abort();
    if (scrollAmount == WHEEL_PAGESCROLL)
        scrollAmount = t->pagesize;
    if (scrollAmount == 0)      // no mouse wheel scrolling (or t->pagesize == 0)
        return;
    // the rest of this is basically http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/07/54615.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/11/54624.aspx
    // see those pages for information on subtleties
    delta += t->wheelCarry;
    lines = delta * ((int) scrollAmount) / WHEEL_DELTA;
    t->wheelCarry = delta - lines * WHEEL_DELTA / ((int) scrollAmount);
    vscrollby(t, -lines);
}

static void vscroll(struct table *t, WPARAM wParam)
{
    SCROLLINFO si;
    intptr_t newpos;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof (SCROLLINFO));
    si.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;
    if (GetScrollInfo(t->hwnd, SB_VERT, &si) == 0)
        abort();

    newpos = t->firstVisible;
    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
    case SB_TOP:
        newpos = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        newpos = t->count - t->pagesize;
        break;
    case SB_LINEUP:
        newpos--;
        break;
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        newpos++;
        break;
    case SB_PAGEUP:
        newpos -= t->pagesize;
        break;
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        newpos += t->pagesize;
        break;
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
        newpos = (intptr_t) (si.nPos);
        break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        newpos = (intptr_t) (si.nTrackPos);
    }

    vscrollto(t, newpos);
}

static void resize(struct table *t)
{
    RECT r;
    SCROLLINFO si;
    HDLAYOUT headerlayout;
    WINDOWPOS headerpos;

    // do this first so our scrollbar calculations can be correct
    if (GetClientRect(t->hwnd, &r) == 0)        // use the whole client rect
        abort();
    headerlayout.prc = &r;
    headerlayout.pwpos = &headerpos;
    if (SendMessageW(t->header, HDM_LAYOUT, 0, (LPARAM) (&headerlayout)) == FALSE)
        abort();
    if (SetWindowPos(t->header, headerpos.hwndInsertAfter, headerpos.x, headerpos.y, headerpos.cx, headerpos.cy, headerpos.flags | SWP_SHOWWINDOW) == 0)
        abort();
    t->headerHeight = headerpos.cy;

    // now adjust the scrollbars
    r = realClientRect(t);
    t->pagesize = (r.bottom - r.top) / rowHeight(t);
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof (SCROLLINFO));
    si.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = t->count - 1;
    si.nPage = t->pagesize;
    SetScrollInfo(t->hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);

    recomputeHScroll(t);
}

static void drawItems(struct table *t, HDC dc, RECT cliprect)
{
    HFONT thisfont, prevfont;
    LONG height;
    LONG y;
    intptr_t i;
    RECT controlSize;       // for filling the entire selected row
    intptr_t first, last;
    POINT prevOrigin, prevViewportOrigin;

    if (GetClientRect(t->hwnd, &controlSize) == 0)
        abort();

    height = rowHeight(t);

    thisfont = t->font;     // in case WM_SETFONT happens before we return
    prevfont = (HFONT) SelectObject(dc, thisfont);
    if (prevfont == NULL)
        abort();

    // adjust the clip rect and the window so that (0, 0) is always the first item
    // adjust the viewport so that everything is shifted down t->headerHeight pixels
    if (OffsetRect(&cliprect, 0, t->firstVisible * height) == 0)
        abort();
    if (GetWindowOrgEx(dc, &prevOrigin) == 0)
        abort();
    if (SetWindowOrgEx(dc, prevOrigin.x, prevOrigin.y + (t->firstVisible * height), NULL) == 0)
        abort();
    if (SetViewportOrgEx(dc, 0, t->headerHeight, &prevViewportOrigin) == 0)
        abort();

    // see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/29/54591.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/30/54600.aspx
    first = cliprect.top / height;
    if (first < 0)
        first = 0;
    last = (cliprect.bottom + height - 1) / height;
    if (last >= t->count)
        last = t->count;

    y = first * height;
    for (i = first; i < last; i++) {
        RECT rsel;
        HBRUSH background;
        int textColor;
        WCHAR msg[100];
        RECT headeritem;
        intptr_t j;
        LRESULT xoff;

        // TODO verify these two
        background = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        textColor = COLOR_WINDOWTEXT;
        if (t->selected == i) {
            // these are the colors wine uses (http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/comctl32/listview.c)
            // the two for unfocused are also suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428710/windows-forms-inactive-highlight-color
            background = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_HIGHLIGHT + 1);
            textColor = COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT;
            if (GetFocus() != t->hwnd) {
                background = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
                textColor = COLOR_BTNTEXT;
            }
        }

        // first fill the selection rect
        rsel.left = controlSize.left;
        rsel.top = y;
        rsel.right = controlSize.right - controlSize.left;
        rsel.bottom = y + height;
        if (FillRect(dc, &rsel, background) == 0)
            abort();

        xoff = SendMessageW(t->header, HDM_GETBITMAPMARGIN, 0, 0);

        // now draw the cells
        if (SetTextColor(dc, GetSysColor(textColor)) == CLR_INVALID)
            abort();
        if (SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT) == 0)
            abort();
        for (j = 0; j < t->nColumns; j++) {
            if (SendMessageW(t->header, HDM_GETITEMRECT, (WPARAM) j, (LPARAM) (&headeritem)) == 0)
                abort();

            if (j == 1) {           // TODO
                IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS ip;

                ZeroMemory(&ip, sizeof (IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS));
                ip.cbSize = sizeof (IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS);
                ip.himl = t->imagelist;
                ip.i = 0;
                ip.hdcDst = dc;
                ip.x = headeritem.left + xoff;
                ip.y = y;
                ip.cx = 0;      // draw whole image
                ip.cy = 0;
                ip.xBitmap = 0;
                ip.yBitmap = 0;
                ip.rgbBk = CLR_NONE;
                ip.fStyle = ILD_NORMAL | ILD_SCALE;     // TODO alpha-blend; ILD_DPISCALE?
                // TODO ILS_ALPHA?
                if (ImageList_DrawIndirect(&ip) == 0)
                    abort();
                continue;
            }
            rsel.left = headeritem.left + xoff;
            rsel.top = y;
            rsel.right = headeritem.right;
            rsel.bottom = y + height;
            // TODO vertical center in case the height is less than the icon height?
            if (DrawTextExW(dc, msg, wsprintf(msg, L"Item %d", i), &rsel, DT_END_ELLIPSIS | DT_LEFT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE, NULL) == 0)
                abort();
        }
        y += height;
    }

    // reset everything
    if (SetViewportOrgEx(dc, prevViewportOrigin.x, prevViewportOrigin.y, NULL) == 0)
        abort();
    if (SetWindowOrgEx(dc, prevOrigin.x, prevOrigin.y, NULL) == 0)
        abort();
    if (SelectObject(dc, prevfont) != (HGDIOBJ) (thisfont))
        abort();
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK tableWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    struct table *t;
    HDC dc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    NMHDR *nmhdr = (NMHDR *) lParam;
    NMHEADERW *nm = (NMHEADERW *) lParam;

    t = (struct table *) GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    if (t == NULL) {
        // we have to do things this way because creating the header control will fail mysteriously if we create it first thing
        // (which is fine; we can get the parent hInstance this way too)
        if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
            CREATESTRUCTW *cs = (CREATESTRUCTW *) lParam;

            t = (struct table *) malloc(sizeof (struct table));
            if (t == NULL)
                abort();
            ZeroMemory(t, sizeof (struct table));
            t->hwnd = hwnd;
            // TODO this should be a global
            t->defaultFont = (HFONT) GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT);
            if (t->defaultFont == NULL)
                abort();
            t->font = t->defaultFont;
t->selected = 5;t->count=100;//TODO
            t->header = CreateWindowExW(0,
                WC_HEADERW, L"",
                // TODO is HOTTRACK needed?
                WS_CHILD | HDS_FULLDRAG | HDS_HORZ | HDS_HOTTRACK,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                t->hwnd, (HMENU) 100, cs->hInstance, NULL);
            if (t->header == NULL)
                abort();
{HDITEMW item;
ZeroMemory(&item, sizeof (HDITEMW));
item.mask = HDI_WIDTH | HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT;
item.cxy = 200;
item.pszText = L"Column";
item.fmt = HDF_LEFT | HDF_STRING;
if (SendMessage(t->header, HDM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM) (&item)) == (LRESULT) (-1))
abort();
ZeroMemory(&item, sizeof (HDITEMW));
item.mask = HDI_WIDTH | HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT;
item.cxy = 150;
item.pszText = L"Column 2";
item.fmt = HDF_LEFT | HDF_STRING;
if (SendMessage(t->header, HDM_INSERTITEM, 1, (LPARAM) (&item)) == (LRESULT) (-1))
abort();
t->nColumns=2;
t->imagelist = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1);
if(t->imagelist==NULL)abort();
{
HICON icon;
int unused;
icon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_ERROR);
if(icon == NULL)abort();
if (ImageList_AddIcon(t->imagelist, icon) == -1)abort();
if (ImageList_GetIconSize(t->imagelist, &unused, &(t->imagelistHeight)) == 0)abort();
}
}
            SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) t);
        }
        // even if we did the above, fall through
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        if (dc == NULL)
            abort();
        drawItems(t, dc, ps.rcPaint);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_SETFONT:
        t->font = (HFONT) wParam;
        if (t->font == NULL)
            t->font = t->defaultFont;
        // also set the header font
        SendMessageW(t->header, WM_SETFONT, wParam, lParam);
        if (LOWORD(lParam) != FALSE) {
            // the scrollbar page size will change so redraw that too
            // also recalculate the header height
            // TODO do that when this is FALSE too somehow
            resize(t);
            redrawAll(t);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_GETFONT:
        return (LRESULT) t->font;
    case WM_VSCROLL:
        vscroll(t, wParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        wheelscroll(t, wParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_SIZE:
        resize(t);
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        selectItem(t, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        // all we need to do here is redraw the highlight
        // TODO localize to just the selected item
        // TODO ensure giving focus works right
        redrawAll(t);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        keySelect(t, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    // TODO header double-click
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if (nmhdr->hwndFrom == t->header)
            switch (nmhdr->code) {
            // I could use HDN_TRACK but wine doesn't emit that
            case HDN_ITEMCHANGING:
            case HDN_ITEMCHANGED:       // TODO needed?
                recomputeHScroll(t);
                redrawAll(t);
                return FALSE;
            }
        // otherwise fall through
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    abort();
    return 0;       // unreached
}

void makeTableWindowClass(void)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = tableWindowClass;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = tableWndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);     // TODO correct?
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0)
        abort();
}

int main(void)
{
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;

    ZeroMemory(&icc, sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    if (InitCommonControlsEx(&icc) == 0)
        abort();
    makeTableWindowClass();
    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        tableWindowClass, L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400, 400,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (mainwin == NULL)
        abort();
    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    if (UpdateWindow(mainwin) == 0)
        abort();
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`t->firstVisible` is the first visible row; `t->pagesize` is the number of rows per vscroll page, and `t->headerHeight` is the height of the header control in pixels. `t->wheelcarry` is the mouse wheel carryover, from this.

The actual height of a row is calculated by the `rowHeight()` function, which `vscrollto()`, the routine that actually calls `ScrolLWindow()`, multiplies the new `t->firstVisible` by to figure out how many pixels to scroll.

The `realClientRect()` logic in `vscrollto()` is to make sure that only the content area gets scrolled, and not the header control.

For drawing, I change the window origin to make (0, 0) be the first item (row 0) no matter what and then I change the viewport origin to account for the header. Readers of MSDN will note that this sounds strange (the documentation for both `SetWindowOrgEx()` and `SetViewportOrgEx()` say you generally don't use both), but my attempts at accounting for the header height manually have proven disastrous.

Again, this happens on both real Windows (did this earlier today on Windows 7) and wine.

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Instinctively I would suspect the offset stuff, since as you say it does sound strange. If you manually cause a refresh (e.g. by dragging another window over the top) does the list paint OK? If so, what happens if instead of relying on `ScrollWindowEx` to invalidate the area that needs repainting, you do it yourself with `InvalidateRect`?

Comment: Manually refreshing does redraw everything properly (in fact, it redraws the entire row because of how the painting code is written, regardless of how much is actually drawn). (Tested on Windows XP this time.) Given that, I could just manually refresh everything, yes; I'd still like to know what my bug is (especially if invalidating everything on scroll turns out to perform poorly by comparison).

Comment: In my experience the Win32 ListCtrl can be made to do almost anything and is already highly optimised for rendering performance. Writing your own does seem to be a bit OTT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a play around with your code and I think the problem is definitely caused by your modifying the viewport and window origins. The issue is that adjusting the origins like that changes where new drawing will appear in the window, but it doesn't cause the update region to be shifted as well.

Therefore when there's only a partially invalidated area, as you get when scrolling, some of your drawing is clipped out by the update region.

It's actually not specific to scrolling - you can also see the same effect by dragging your window off the bottom of the screen, and then slowly dragging it back into view. The window will end up completely blank. If you comment out your call to `SetViewportOrgEx` the problem goes away completely.

You could probably solve this by adjusting the clipping region as well - you'd have to get the current update region, shift it by the same offset, and reselect it into the DC. Alternatively, you could redesign your painting code to take the height of the header into account when painting rather than shifting the viewport offset. You mentioned you had other issues when doing this - I suspect it will be easier to solve those than you think (i.e. it seems like a bit of an XY problem).

Comment: I got rid of ALL the origin manipulation and did everything relative to the first visible row now. It seems a little nonsensical ([but maybe it's just me?](http://pastie.org/9701623)) but it works. Thanks again!